# TGCA LAML rsem data

Tags: rna-seq

How do I test the gene expression differences between multiple groups?

I have normalized TCGA RSEM data, this is the dataset
**Human__TCGA_LAML__UNC__RNAseq__HiSeq_RNA__01_28_2016__BI__Gene__Firehose_RSEM_log2.cct**.

I have different groups of data which were defined in terms of blast percentage as well as karyotype. Here I dont have control sample as such but I do have normal karyotype. Now since these are all already normalized data what would be ideal test to find the differences.

What methods can I use if I have to compare between these different sub types of data? So far I have always used raw counts and used DESeq2 to perform differential and other downstream analysis how in this case should I go ahead?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to find the important or significant genes that defines a particular subtypes of cancer in this AML.

So far I have tried clustering and PCA on it I do see some clusters and patterns. Now I want to take those cluster for downstream analysis such as pathways plus we want to validate some of the key genes that might come out.

So far I have done as such I get raw counts which i use with deseq2 to run differential analysis between multiple groups or subypes.

How to do the same here when I don't have raw counts to start?